# Drawing the "Seed of Life" without redrawing anything

Tags: recursion, graphics

I have a mildly interesting problem which I can't quite figure out (although in fairness, I am pretty drunk)

The "[Seed of Life](https://www.google.com/search?q=seed%20of%20life)" is a pattern created from drawing circles of equal radius, centred on the intersection of the previous circle.

Language doesn't really matter, the theory is more important here. Anything which can draw a circle will do it. For example, HTML5 + JS canvas can do it. It's a lovely example of how recursion can help solve problems.

The problem is that a naive approach will end up redrawing many, many circles. With 7 layers, you'll end up with over 300,000 circle draws.

A simple approach is to maintain a list of previous circle centre points, and only draw circles which are not in that list.

My question is whether there's a "better" way to approach this? Something which doesn't require checking that list.

A fun problem to ponder.

Comment: Can't you "save" the current canvas and just draw new circles upon that image?
You will need to keep track of the previous circle-positions but these won't have to be redrawn every time

Comment: Yes you can, that's not really the issue though. The issue is that if each circle has six "children" around it, at least one of those will overlap with the children of its neighbors.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have this solved thanks to a friend. I'll post here what I'm doing now in case someone ever is curious.

In short, starting from the center and working out, calculate the vertices of a hexagon, and subdivide each edge of the hexagon into `i` number of places, where `i` is the layer number.

I drew it in C# using SkiaSharp, but the code is nothing special to the language, there's no reason this couldn't be written in any language. Here's the significant bits:

```
const float seedAngle = (float)(Math.PI / 3.0);

static void SeedOfLifeDemo(int x, int y) {
    //setting up Skia stuff, this will be different depending what language you're using.
    var info = new SKImageInfo(x, y);
    using var bitmap = FlatImage(info, SKColors.White);

    SKCanvas canvas = new SKCanvas(bitmap);
    float radius = Math.Min(x, y) / 15;

    SKPoint center = new SKPoint(x / 2f, y / 2f);

    SKPaint strokePaint = new SKPaint {
        Color = SKColors.Black,
        Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
        StrokeWidth = 1,
        IsAntialias = true,
    };

    int layers = 4;
    //Draw the very central circle. This is just a little easier than adding that edge case to SubdividedHexagonAboutPoint
    canvas.DrawCircle(center, radius, strokePaint);
    for (int i = 1; i <= layers; i++) {
        foreach (SKPoint p in SubdividedHexagonAboutPoint(center, radius * i, i)) {
            canvas.DrawCircle(p, radius, strokePaint);
        }
    }
    SaveImage(bitmap, "SeedOfLifeFastDemo.Jpg");//More Skia specific stuff
}

//The magic!
static List<SKPoint> SubdividedHexagonAboutPoint(SKPoint centre, float radius, int subdivisions) {
    List<SKPoint> points = new List<SKPoint>(6 * subdivisions);
    SKPoint? prevPoint = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {//Step around the circle. The 7th step is to close the last edge
        float x = (float)(Math.Sin(seedAngle * i) * radius + centre.X);
        float y = (float)(Math.Cos(seedAngle * i) * radius + centre.Y);

        SKPoint point = new SKPoint(x, y);
        if (prevPoint != null) {
            points.Add(point);//include the "primary" 6 points
            if (subdivisions > 0) {
                float xDist = (point.X - prevPoint.Value.X) / subdivisions;
                float yDist = (point.Y - prevPoint.Value.Y) / subdivisions;

                for (int sub = 1; sub < subdivisions; sub++) {
                    SKPoint subPoint = new SKPoint(point.X - xDist * sub, point.Y - yDist * sub);
                    points.Add(subPoint);//include the edge subdivisions
                }
            }
        }
        prevPoint = point;
    }
    return points;
}
```

This is quite an interesting exercise really, and another example of where recursion can really bite you when used badly.